# Is it possible to call function from another Python file on Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When creating Python script on Jupyter, **is it possible to call a function from another Python file?**

When I try to call, it works on Terminal but does not work on Jupyter.

Comment: You can always `import` other .py files to access their functions.

Answer (score 3):

For example, suppose I have a `Person.py` file and it is in the working directory of my current jupyter notebook. Furthermore, suppose it is simple and here it is

```
def get_rss(y, x):
    x = sm.add_constant(x)
    results=sm.OLS(y, x).fit()
    rss= (results.resid**2).sum()
    N=results.nobs
    K=results.df_model
    return rss, N, K, results

def myfunc(d):
    print("Hello my name is " + d)
```

When I try to call, it works on Terminal but does not work on Jupyter.
When I try to call it as `import Person`, it works on Jupyter cell but I can not access the functions inside of it.

For example, if you tried writing this in Jupyter Notebook you might get this message after typing this
    Person.myfunc('ds')

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-63fdc0f35859> in <module>
----> 1 Person.myfunc('ds')

AttributeError: module 'Person' has no attribute 'myfunc'
```

## My Advice

Restart your kernel and this should eliminate this problem. I hope this clarifies your question as well could be considered as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just restart the kernel and it should work fine :)

Comment: lol, this was it

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you're already working with other files, I recommend that you stop using jupyter and even terminal aswell.

You can use [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) instead.

If you were just learning, you could use jupyter but if you're already at that stage I recommend you to stick to Pycharm.

Pycharm is a nice IDE, where you can run the files directly on it, and has a lot more cool features.

Also, to use it in jupyter, just import the files you want:

```
import #whatever file you want
```